What's the process of Curvature Jacobian In SmacPlanner/smoother_cost_function base on ros-foxy
I'm learning robot planning algorithm from your code <smac_planner> base on ros-foxy. I am working on implementing CurvatureJacobian and have encountered some challenges
curvature cost function:

u is vector ptm->pt, v is vector pt->ptp, k_max is the maximum limit of curvature.

Derivative of function cost_curvature can be decomposed to the derivative of these functions:

I have finished other functions' derivative, now having trouble on project jacobian of h(x).
My project process:

But in smac_planner/include/smac_planner/smoother_cost_function.hpp/addCurvatureJacobian
project jacobian of h(x) is like:

according to code block
  inline Eigen::Vector2d normalizedOrthogonalComplement(
    const Eigen::Vector2d & a,
    const Eigen::Vector2d & b,
    const double & a_norm,
    const double & b_norm) const
  {
    return (a - (a.dot(b) * b / b.squaredNorm())) / (a_norm * b_norm);
  }

  {
    ...

    auto neg_pt_plus = -1 * pt_p;
    Eigen::Vector2d p1 = normalizedOrthogonalComplement(
      pt, neg_pt_plus, curvature_params.delta_xi_norm, curvature_params.delta_xi_p_norm);
    Eigen::Vector2d p2 = normalizedOrthogonalComplement(
      neg_pt_plus, pt, curvature_params.delta_xi_p_norm, curvature_params.delta_xi_norm);

    ...

    const Eigen::Vector2d jacobian = u *
      (common_prefix * (-p1 - p2) - (common_suffix * d_delta_xi_d_xi));
  }

I guess (-p1 - p2) is jacobian of h(x).
My curvature jacobian is different from that in smac_planner source.
I wonder what I miss in project jacobian of h(x) ? If possible, could any dalao kindly share the curvature jabobian process.
